# XLLoop (Excel 2010) - Integrating a java function that returns an array/list of values

Tags: java, arrays, excel, excel-2010

I've started looking at [XLLoop](http://xlloop.sourceforge.net/) as I need a way of getting data from a java system into Excel (2010 version).

I've followed the java SimpleServer example on the front page of the website:

```
package org.boris.xlloop.util;

import org.boris.xlloop.FunctionServer;
import org.boris.xlloop.handler.*;
import org.boris.xlloop.reflect.*;

public class ServerExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create function server on the default port
        FunctionServer fs = new FunctionServer();

        // Create a reflection function handler and add the Math methods
        ReflectFunctionHandler rfh = new ReflectFunctionHandler();
        rfh.addMethods("Math.", Math.class);
        rfh.addMethods("Math.", Maths.class);
        rfh.addMethods("CSV.", CSV.class);
        rfh.addMethods("Reflect.", Reflect.class);

        // Create a function information handler to register our functions
        FunctionInformationHandler firh = new FunctionInformationHandler();
        firh.add(rfh.getFunctions());

        // Set the handlers
        CompositeFunctionHandler cfh = new CompositeFunctionHandler();
        cfh.add(rfh);
        cfh.add(firh);
        fs.setFunctionHandler(new DebugFunctionHandler(cfh));

        // Run the engine
        System.out.println("Listening on port " + fs.getPort() + "...");
        fs.run();
    }
}
```

and have successfully been able to integrate simple static java methods into Excel that return one value. E.g.Math.random(), Math.pow(2, 4.45) which both return a single double.

However, I have been unable to integrate any functions that return an array/list of values. For example, in the above we have registered the Maths class (an XLLoop class) for use in Excel. This class contains a static method

```
public static double[] normalDist(int var0)
```

The method returns an array of length **var0**, however when I call this in Excel only one cell is populated with a value, I would have expected **var0** cells to have been populated. This seems like a fairly fundamental feature to me, so I'm pretty sure I must be doing something daft.

If there is anyone out there who could help with this it would be greatly appreciated.

I should also mention that I found a [similar SO question](http://www.inside-r.org/questions/using-xlloop-execute-r-functions-excel-return-more-one-value) , linked from a R related SO questions feed. Unfortunately the original [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615518/using-xlloop-to-execute-r-functions-in-excel-that-return-more-than-one-value)  has been removed from SO by the poster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter the function calling the method that returns an array as a matrix-function in excel: select the cells that shall recieve the returned data, enter the function and hit ctrl-shift-enter.
If the range selected is too small, then only the values fitting in the range are displayed.